# How to split a "formula" in R

Tags: r, r-package

I'm trying to make a small R package with my limited knowledge in R programming. I am trying to use the following argument:

```
formula=~a+b*X
```

where X is vector, 'a' and 'b' are constants in a function call.

What I'm wondering is once I input the formula, I want to extract `(a,b)` and X separately and use them for other data manipulations inside the function call. Is there a way to do it in R?

I would really appreciate any guidance.

**Note: Edited my question for clarity**

I'm looking for something similar to model.matrix() output. The above mentioned formula can be more generalized to accommodate 'n' number of variables, say,

> ~2+3*X +4*Y+...+2*Z

In the output, I need the coefficients  (2 3 4 ...2) as a vector and [1 X Y ... Z] as a covariate matrix.

Comment: This isn't super clear. It seems to me, X is data that the user enters, while a and b might be parameters to be estimated. If so, X is provided by the user and a and be are returned values from some estimation function. Note that in R, formula=... is referred to as an argument, not an option (Stata background?). My advice: play around with extracting coefficients from `lm` `glm`, and `nls` for a week or so. Then move on to this project.

Comment: @Imo Sorry, if its not clear. I mean to say i'm passing the "formula" argument in my function and user can  input a,b, and X as a polynomial. I should say, a and b are constants rather than parameters in this case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question is not completely clear so we will assume that the question is, given a formula using standard formula syntax, how do we parse out the variables names (or in the second answer the variable names and constants) giving as output a character vector containing them.

**1) all.vars** Try this:

```
fo <- a + b * X  # input
all.vars(fo)
```

giving:

```
[1] "a" "b" "X"
```

**2) strapplyc** Also we could do it with string manipulation.  In this case it also parses out the constants.

```
library(gsubfn)
fo <- ~ 25 + 35 * X  # input
strapplyc(gsub(" ", "", format(fo)), "-?[0-9.]+|[a-zA-Z0-9._]+", simplify = unlist)
```

giving:

```
[1] "25" "35" "X"
```

**Note:** If all you are trying to do is to *evaluate* the RHS of the formula as an R expression then it is just:

```
X <- 1:3
fo <- ~ 1 + 2 * X
eval(fo[[2]])
```

giving:

```
[1] 3 5 7
```

**Update:** Fixed and added second solution and Note.

Comment: If 'a' and 'b' are  constants, a.vars won't work as it returns only X.  I'm looking for (a,b) and the vector X.

Comment: @user20650, Here formula is a user input, a and b are constant values and X is a covariate vector.  The situation is similar to lm() /predict.lm() function, but i don't have a response variable and I'm not trying to fit the model. If I can extract the coefficients (or constants in this case), say (a,b)  and X vector, I can pass these to another function inside the current function call.  a+b*X can be generalized to a multi linear form. Hope this is more clear now.

Comment: Thanks. The second method using strapplyc() is interesting, but is there a way to do this without calling any other library. Also, how do I get the values stored in X?  I do want to incorporate more variables  and extract each of them along with the constants. Any thoughts?

Comment: `get("X")` will get the value of variable whose name is "X".   See `?get` for additional arguments.  See `?regmatches` to use a base function.

Answer (score 6):

A call is a list of symbols and/or other calls and its elements can be accessed through normal indexing operations, e.g.

```
f <- ~a+bX
f[[1]]
#`~`
f[[2]]
#a + bX
f[[2]][[1]]
#`+`
f[[2]][[2]]
#a
```

However notice that in your formula `bX` is one symbol, you probably meant `b * X` instead.

```
f <- ~a + b * X
```

Then `a` and `b` typically would be stored in an unevaluated list.

```
vars <- call('list', f[[2]][[2]], f[[2]][[3]][[2]])
vars
#list(a, b)
```

and `vars` would be passed to `eval` at some point.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out b*X. How do I get the values stored in X?  Can i generalize f, e.g: f <-  2+ 3.5*X+Y+z...? Any comments?

Comment: The `X` is in `f[[2]][[3]][[3]]`. To generalize you need to write a parser that finds and extracts the elements from the formula, which depending on the type of formula can be complicated.

Comment: @ Ernest A:  Formula can have "n" number of variables with coefficients, e.g: 2+3*x+4*y+0.1*z.  With my limited knowledge in R programming, its not that easy to digest what you mentioned about parser. Can you please provide some examples to write a parser. Thanks!

Comment: You can look up `?terms` and related documentation, but unless you are willing to invest a lot of time studying the internals of R I would advise that you try a different approach. Perhaps you don't really need a formula object. A simple list may be enough if you simply need to specify some coefficients along with labels.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into that.